# ¿Como puedo poner el icono de un xml en una pagina html/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Estoy tratando de poner un icono del xml de tutiempo.net en una pagina de prueba html con javascript, pero no se como hacer para visualizar tal icono.

**Codigo xml**

```
 <dia>
        <fecha>2019-1-21</fecha>
        <fecha_larga>Lunes 21 de Enero</fecha_larga>
        <temp_maxima>13</temp_maxima>
        <temp_minima>3</temp_minima>
        <icono>http://i5.tutiempo.net/wi/01/50/1.png</icono>
        <texto>Despejado</texto>
        <humedad>74</humedad>
        <viento>13</viento>
        <dir_viento>Nordeste</dir_viento>
        <ico_viento>http://i5.tutiempo.net/eltiempo/DirViento/NE.png</ico_viento>
        <salida_sol>8:44</salida_sol>
        <puesta_sol>18:34</puesta_sol>
        <salida_luna>19:08</salida_luna>
        <puesta_luna>08:54</puesta_luna>
        <ico_fase_luna>http://i5.tutiempo.net/Fases/FasesFB50/Luna15.gif</ico_fase_luna>
    </dia>
```

**Codigo html**

```
function myFunction(xml) {
    var i;
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var table="<tr><th>Fecha</th><th>Temperatura max</th><th>Temperatura min</th><th></th><th></th><th>Humedad</th><th>Viento</th></tr>";
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("dia");
    for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
        table += "<tr><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("fecha_larga")[0].childNodes[0].textContent +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("temp_maxima")[0].childNodes[0].textContent +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("temp_minima")[0].childNodes[0].textContent +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("icono")[0].childNodes[0].textContent +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("texto")[0].childNodes[0].textContent +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("humedad")[0].childNodes[0].textContent +
            "</td><td>"+
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("viento")[0].childNodes[0].textContent +
            "</td></tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
```

**Y esto es lo que me saca**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que incluir la ruta dentro de un elemento `img`.

Basicamente tienes que sustituir

```
<td>"+x[i].getElementsByTagName("icono")[0].childNodes[0].textContent + "</td>
```

por

```
<td><img src='"+x[i].getElementsByTagName("icono")[0].childNodes[0].textContent + "'/></td>
```

Debería quedar así

```
function myFunction(xml) {
    var i;
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var table="<tr><th>Fecha</th><th>Temperatura max</th><th>Temperatura min</th><th></th><th></th><th>Humedad</th><th>Viento</th></tr>";
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("dia");
    for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
        table += "<tr><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("fecha_larga")[0].childNodes[0].textContent +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("temp_maxima")[0].childNodes[0].textContent +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("temp_minima")[0].childNodes[0].textContent +
            "</td><td><img src='" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("icono")[0].childNodes[0].textContent +
            "' /></td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("texto")[0].childNodes[0].textContent +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("humedad")[0].childNodes[0].textContent +
            "</td><td>"+
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("viento")[0].childNodes[0].textContent +
            "</td></tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
```